# Where is nuget.exe?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm using Visual Studo 2015 and I have Package Manager Console where I can run like

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Visual Studio seems to come with nuget, but what is the location of nuget.exe?

Or Package Manager Console doesn't use nuget.exe?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 uses various NuGet assemblies but it does not itself include NuGet.exe.

NuGet.exe can be downloaded from the NuGet web site:

https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Comment: [For 2017 (same answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326748/nuget-cli-in-visual-studio-2017-how-to-run)

Comment: After downloading the command line tool from https://www.nuget.org/downloads you should find nuget.exe in %SystemRoot%\system32 - most likely C:\Windows\System32

Comment: As far as I know, If You have Visual studio you can find a copy of nuget.exe in C:\Windows\System32\.nuget\

Answer (score 19):

Another great option nowadays is to use `winget` (if you have Windows 10 v1709 or greater). In the Command Prompt, enter:

`winget install Microsoft.NuGet`

*(below follows some extra information for the curious mind)* This will:

1. Install the official `nuget.exe` in your PC.
2. Create a Symbolic Link here: `%localappdata%\microsoft\winget\links`
3. Make the `nuget.exe` globally available for your user to call it from anywhere, since the aforementioned directory should be present in your user's PATH variable.

Comment: Run winget as administrator, to prevent: "This command requires administrator privileges to execute." And after installation, reboot if you want a newly opened command shell to pick up the new path.

Comment: how to Create a Symbolic Link here: %localappdata%\microsoft\winget\links ??

Comment: @Urasquirrel, if you're using the `winget install` command above, you don't have to create the Symbolic Link yourself. The `winget` will do it for you. The 3 steps above are just out of curiosity.

Comment: Where is winget.exe?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins,
if you have Windows 10 v1709 or greater, the `winget.exe` application will be globally available for you, just like any other Windows tool such as `Notepad.exe` or `Paint.exe`.

To check which version of Windows you're running, type `winver` in the Run utility.

Comment: After installing the `Microsoft.NuGet` package using `winget`, the executable is in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\Microsoft.NuGet_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\nuget.exe`