# How do you programatically find out where NuGet.exe is installled on a given machine?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

Assuming that I have a script that will be run on a clean build server with Nuget.exe installed on it, what is the best way to programatically determine the path for where NuGet.exe is installed?

Is there a way to infer its location by going through NuGet.targets, or reading some sort of external config file, or following some sort of convention?

Note: The closest question I've seen so far is [this one that points to where NuGet can be downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349547/where-is-nuget-exe), but I'm not interested in downloading NuGet manually. I need a way to determine where it is installed, but I'm not sure if there's a convention that I can follow to determine where it might be installed.

Comment: Usually, if you install nuget on a server, you also add it to `PATH` so you don't have to worry about installation directory. Other then that nuget.exe is like any other file - you can check default install directory, or always install it in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

In general, nuget.exe is not shipped with any product. Most people need to manually download it.

The only exception is for people who install Mono. Mono ships nuget.exe, but that's generally limited to people developing on Linux or Mac. But people who use .NET Core exclusively don't need Mono, even on Linux/Mac, so they won't have it either.

Few developers on Windows install Mono, so chances are you don't have a nuget.exe on your system unless you downloaded it yourself, or someone checked it into a repo that you cloned.